# magento 2 product align alphabetical order in pdf invoice

Tags: magento-2.0, magento2.2.6

**how we can arrange product alphabetically order in PDF invoice if any extension please suggest me or code please share it**

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? It’s ridiculous that it isn’t an option.
Thanks Mark.

Comment: yes i did fix it

Answer (score 0):

**Create an extension use the code  Plugin/Invoice.php**

```
<?php
```

namespace Zesh\Invoice\Plugin;

class Invoice{
protected $authSession;
public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession)
{
$this->authSession=$authSession;

}

```
public function afterGetAllItems(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice $subject,$items)
{
    $filter_InvoiceItems=[];
    $CurrentUserId=$this->authSession->getUser()->getUserId();
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $orderitemrepo = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface');
    
    $alphabet = [];
   foreach($items as $row) 
    {
        $item_id=$row->getOrderItemId();
        $Item_recorde=$orderitemrepo->get($item_id);
        $alphabet[] = ltrim($Item_recorde->getData('name'));
    }
   $alphabet[] = sort($alphabet);
   


     
  $arrlength = count($alphabet);
```

for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {

```
    foreach ($items as $row)
    {
        
        
        $item_id=$row->getOrderItemId();
   
        $Item_recorde=$orderitemrepo->get($item_id);
        if($Item_recorde->getData('name') == $alphabet[$x]){
            $filter_InvoiceItems[]=$row;
        }
    }  }
    $array = array_unique($filter_InvoiceItems, SORT_REGULAR);
    return $array;
}
```

}